# PhoneGap open native map

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm a new to phonegap and are having a problem opening the native google map application in phonegap. I have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              $('#btnMap').bind('tap', function(){
                             var url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Restaurant&53.9999,6.7899&z=15';
                             window.location = url;
                             });
          </script>
```

HTML:

```
<a class="buttonleft" id="#btnMap">Map</a>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your html element id is the problem.

```
<a class="buttonleft" id="#btnMap">Map</a>
```

should be:

```
<a class="buttonleft" id="btnMap">Map</a>
```

Just remove the '#'.
I'm assuming you are using jquery.

Comment: Thanks, tried removing the #, but it still doesn't work. When I run it on my phone and click the button the screen goes white for a second as if it is opening a program but then goes back to the same screen. Is there any specific code I need to import in the header? Does it matter where I put my javascript? I also can't get a href="tel:0123456789" to work. Would this be related?

Comment: I don't think they are related. [Here is an article that may help with the phone issue](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers)

Comment: Realised I had forgotten to add rel="external". That solved the phone call issue and for the map I changed it to open without JS. <a class="buttonleft" href="maps:q=...." rel="external">

Answer (score 3):

The [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) say that opening a regular url like `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=...&ll=...` will load the native maps app, but that isn't working for me in iOS 5.1.  Using the `maps:q=...&ll=...` protocol is working.